# iOS tinting button and popover

Tags: ios, objective-c

When a popover is displayed, does it change the tint of all components?

I have a button with a segue to display a popover, and when its selected I can change the tint color of the button, but when the popover is displayed, it changes the tint color of the button, only after dismissing the popover, the button returns to the highlight color. Any idea of how to solve this?

***Edit
If I set a tint color like black, white, or black with alpha, it works, it seems that only works with grayscale, If I try with blue, or red, or any rgb value it doesn't work. Is this a bug or is this a default behaviour? Is there a way to do this without adding images for each state?

Comment: Which version of iOS? Under iOS 7 it is part of the new look that various UI components get dimmed in cases like this.

Comment: this is on ios 7 beta 5

Comment: Why aren't you using the GM that came out yesterday? Using a month old beta is a BAD idea.

Comment: I will try with the new version

Comment: The behavior will be the same. This is by design.

Comment: Then how can I make the button to be pressed after showing the popup?